# should i include classes that are part of the java API in my class-diagram?

Tags: java, api, class-diagram

Should i include classes that are part of the Java API, such as `HttpURLConnection` or `JSONObject` in my class diagram, or should i include only the classes that was developed for the project?

My Program connecting to a server, retrieving data, constructing a `JSONObject` then uses this data to construct some objects.
I feel these classes are part of the flow, but I'm just using them - often, but just using - not inheriting or implementing an interface.

So, on one hand i feel they are important, on the other they are not part of my project as a contract or a super-class.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you provide some more inputs. Generally speaking I don't.

Comment: I think you should only include classes which are part of your project.

Answer (score 1):

This of course goes with personal taste. But I personally tend not to include them. Or only refer to them by name but without the properties/methods listed to bring in the point that we don't control this class.

Answer (score 0):

If I looked at a system and felt like a class diagram would be important to have, I'd be inclined to take a step back and see if there are best practices that were missed, such as [Prefer Composition over Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

But, if I was being forced to provide one, I would not include API classes in general, but only where absolutely essential.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve / communicate with your UML diagram?

Does including these classes help achieving that?

Look, there it is. Your answer.

Comment: I can see that you want to teach a guy to fish instead of handing him a fish.  That's commendable.  I'm trying to help you be more effective at it by suggesting that you reword your response to integrate the guidance provided in the FAQ.